# Doc file does not download from UserControl in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have user control which contain a grid with candidate data. There a columns candidate name with template field link button. I have attached a rowcommand event on which I am downloading a word file. I have download doc file code which download my doc file from simple web page but this code is not working on user control. Can any one help me to out this problem. its giving the error response is not available

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdCandidate" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
       OnRowDataBound="grdCandidate_RowDataBound" 
       onrowcommand="grdCandidate_RowCommand">
          <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Candidate ID" HeaderText="Candidate ID" />
                 <asp:TemplateField>
                      <HeaderTemplate>
                            Candidate Name
                      </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkResume" CommandName="Download" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Candidate ID") %>'
                                runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Candidate Name") %>' ToolTip='<%# "Download Resume - " + Eval("Candidate Name") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
             </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>

protected void grdCandidate_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Download")
        {
            byte[] Attachment = null;
            string Extension = string.Empty;
            string Resume = "Resume";
            ClsCandidateManager objCandidateManager = new ClsCandidateManager();
            ClsSecureManager objSecureManager = new ClsSecureManager();
            Attachment = objCandidateManager.GetCandidateAttachment(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument), out Extension);
            if (Attachment != null && Attachment.Length > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Response.Clear();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.Charset = "";
                    if (Extension == ".pdf")
                    {
                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.ContentType = "application/vsd-msword";
                    }
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + Resume + Extension);

                    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                    Response.BinaryWrite(Attachment);                        
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.End();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string str = ex.Message + ex.InnerException;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "SymbolError", "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Resume is not Uploaded !');</script>");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string str = ex.Message + ex.InnerException;

    }
```

Comment: Is your gridview or your user control inside update panel?

Comment: No Pawan i m not using Updatepanel,i think this issue from UserControl i create usrcontrol

Comment: this code is working fine when i use this code in simple form but here web user control its not working.

Comment: hmm The code needs to be debugged properly. I don't think this can be done without having the code itself. Sorry!

Comment: but i already debug the code its working but does not download file same code i use on other pages where its working fine

Comment: I just meant if I could have code I could debug it and test, without that I am helpless :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32056/discussion-between-sandeep-and-pawan-nogariya)

Comment: Are you adding usercontrol dynamically to your aspx page? If yes, then the postback will be lost.

Comment: hi Deepu,ya i m adding dynamically so how i can get response i wan download my doc file

Answer (score 0):

Use the UpdatePanel as shown below,

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkDownload" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```