# Download file from a user control wrapped in a master page update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I a have problem sounds strange to me! I am going to download a file using asp.net C# from a user control. Here is the structure of my web forms:

1. There is a Site.Master file in which the content place holder is wrapped  with an update panel
2. There is User Control named Library.ascx that display lists of books so that users may download each of which they like to. ***Note that, books are displayed using a ListView web control.***
3. The above user control is used in different pages at the same web site (imagine a school website that includes different levels and each of which has a library page)

The code to download the file is as the following:

```
  protected void listViewBooks_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName != "Download") return;

        var books = _lib.GetBookInfo(Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
        var filePath = string.Empty;

        foreach (var s in books)
        {
            filePath = s.FilePath;
        }

        var fileName = filePath.Substring(filePath.LastIndexOf(@"/", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1);
        filePath = Server.MapPath("~/PDF/") + fileName;

        var file = new FileInfo(filePath);

        if (!file.Exists) return;

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-length", file.Length.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Actually, it goes up to the line before **Response.End()** and I don't know why it never catches the last bracket of the event, i.e. "}" and from the view point of users nothing happens! I have searched the web and similar questions for hours, but couldn't find any solution! For example, [this linke](http://www.devtoolshed.com/aspnet-download-file-web-browser) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206344/doc-file-does-not-download-from-usercontrol-in-asp-net) and some other ones 
Any help highly appreciated!

Comment: Wouldn't a [generic web handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) be a better solution?

Comment: Actually, I have no experience a generic web handler but thanks for the link, perhaps it helps me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It never reaches the last bracket because you are using [Response.End()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524629%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The End method causes the Web server to stop processing the script and return the current result. The remaining contents of the file are not processed.

You can't download a file from an `UpdatePanel`. You have to trigger a full postback instead.

Comment: Actually I handled the trigger too though not included in the code I have sent but nothing changed. And Thank you for saying the note about Response.End() I didn't know that.

Comment: You were right about the post back matter as I mentioned on my own answer it was misplaced but any how I prefer mark you as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've come over the issue I rose yesterday. Since the flow of the code in the specified user control I had to write the update panel trigger code inside the list view data bound event, and it simply resolved :) thanks for the guys helped me on this.